# Using a new azure webjobs storage for the azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

we have a set of blob trigger functions and we are planning to use a new azure webjobs storage for these azure functions. My question is: since the new storage account doesn't have any track of the already processed file, will the blobs be reprocessed? If yes, can we avoid this reprocessing and in which?

Comment: What's a "azure webjobs storage"?

Comment: Where the azure function data gets stored (queues,azure-webjobs-hosts) etc...

Comment: what makes you to think those blobs will be processed again?

Comment: @Sajeetharan because this is a new blob storage that doesn't have any track about the already processed blobs. I may need to reformulate my question

Comment: I think you need to add more details on the question. what is the logic behind the trigger etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're talking about [Blob Receipt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp#blob-receipts) feature.

When you're using a new azure webjobs storage for the azure function, it definitely re-process the `already processed file`. This is by design.

The only way I can think of is that, when using a new azure webjobs storage, you can add a list which contains all the processed files in your function code, and when the code detects the file is already processed, then do nothing with it.

Comment: thanks. Yes this was actually my idea also, but i have 10k blobs processed. So i need to find a way to query these processed files instead of maintaining a manuelly filled list

Comment: @alaa_sayegh, for query, you can take use a blob sdk, it's easy to list all of the processed files since the processed files will be stored in azure-webjobs-hosts container.